# Should I call `delete` on object allocated using polymorphic allocator

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, allocator, c++pmr

Does polymorphic allocator (I personally use boost and C++17, but guess that it's the same for stl and C++20) in it's destructor automatically destructs objects allocated inside it's memory resource, or should `delete` for each object be called manually, like if I'm using default stl `std::allocator` (where not calling `delete` and then destructing object is an undefined behaviour)?

Comment: Even using `std::allocator` using `delete` **is** undefined behavior. You would need to use the allocator interface to deallocate anything that was allocated through it. **Not** deallocating in the first place is not UB, but leads to resource leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polymorphic allocator is a cheaply copyable object and doesn't own objects.

What you might be confusing it with is a [`memory_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource), which has capacity to store objects. Still, it doesn't own those, because it cannot even know the type(s) of object(s) stored in its capacity.

On the other hand, there are container types that **use** an allocator to allocate storage for their objects. The container **does** own the objects, and **will** destruct them and deallocate from the same (or rather, equivalent) allocator.

In short, you will not be allocating from an allocator, your allocator-aware container will. And it will **not** call delete, but rather the expectable [`allocator.deallocate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/deallocate) or [`allocator.delete_object()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/delete_object) depending on how the allocation was made.

### Example 1: Allocator-Aware Container

Because an example speaks a thousand words:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5vqYTbnT9)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::pmr::vector<X> v;
    v.reserve(3); // watch v reallocate if you remove this line
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
} // v destructs and deallocates automically
```

Prints:

```
X::X()
X::X()
X::X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to see whether your standard library implementation changes behaviour if you remove the call to `reserve()`.

### Example 2: Raw allocator use

It's pretty clear that the allocator interface is not for direct consumption:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W5vxTKcvr)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mem(1024);
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<X>  alloc(&mem);
    {
        auto x1 = alloc.new_object<X>();
        auto x2 = alloc.new_object<X>();
        auto x3 = alloc.new_object<X>();

        // cannot use `operator delete`:
        // delete x1; // Undefined Behaviour

        // need to manually delete the objects we own through the allocator
        alloc.delete_object(x3);
        alloc.delete_object(x2);
        alloc.delete_object(x1);
    }
    { // c++17 interface
        auto x1 = alloc.allocate(sizeof(X)); alloc.construct(x1);
        auto x2 = alloc.allocate(sizeof(X)); alloc.construct(x2);
        auto x3 = alloc.allocate(sizeof(X)); alloc.construct(x3);

        // cannot use `operator delete`:
        // delete x1; // Undefined Behaviour

        // need to manually delete the objects we own through the allocator
        alloc.destroy(x3); alloc.deallocate(x3, sizeof(X));
        alloc.destroy(x2); alloc.deallocate(x2, sizeof(X));
        alloc.destroy(x1); alloc.deallocate(x1, sizeof(X));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
X::X()
X::X()
X::X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::X()
X::X()
X::X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
X::~X()
```

Comment: Note that the second example link actually has address sanitizer enabled, so you can see with your own eyes that calling `delete` on an object obtained from the allocator [leads to Undefined Behaviour](https://godbolt.org/z/1jK9dsdoM)