# is there a problem with std::pmr::memory_resource in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

I'm trying to understand the C++17 memory resources (e.g. memory pools) concept.

I got some part of it working, but if I'm using a memory resource other than new_delete_resource() I get unexpected behaviour. I'm on Visual Studio 2019, but have tried llvm and the Intel 2022 compilers as well.

See the simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //std::pmr::memory_resource* mr = std::pmr::new_delete_resource(); // works
  std::pmr::memory_resource *mr = new std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource(); // does not work
  //std::pmr::memory_resource* mr = new std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource(1000); // does not work
  void* ptr = mr->allocate(sizeof(int));
  int *i1 = new (ptr) int;
  *i1 = 4711;
  ptr = mr->allocate(sizeof(int));
  int* i2 = new (ptr) int;
  *i2 = 815;

  std::cout << *i1 << '\n';
  std::cout << *i2 << '\n';

  delete i1;
  std::cout << *i2 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Is this a bug in VS, i.e. their library implementations?

TK

I would expext to get the same result with all of the three memory resources.

Using a class would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>

class myclass {
public:
  int x;
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //std::pmr::memory_resource* mr = std::pmr::new_delete_resource(); // works
  std::pmr::memory_resource *mr = new std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource(); // does not work
  //std::pmr::memory_resource* mr = new std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource(1000); // does not work
  void* ptr = mr->allocate(sizeof(myclass));
  myclass *c1 = new (ptr) myclass;
  c1->x = 4711;
  ptr = mr->allocate(sizeof(myclass));
  myclass *c2 = new (ptr) myclass;
  c2->x = 815;

  std::cout << c1->x << '\n';
  std::cout << c2->x << '\n';

  c1->~myclass();
  mr->deallocate(c1, sizeof(myclass));
  std::cout << c2->x << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
delete i1;
```

When you use `std::pmr::new_delete_resource`, method `allocate` uses `::operator new` and `deallocate` uses `::operator delete`, as per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new_delete_resource). Since you don't call `deallocate`, but call delete operator through delete expression, `i1` is `::operator delete`'d (dynamic memory deallocated) exactly once as it should be.

But when you use other memory resources, `allocate` allocates memory from preallocated buffer (exact mechanism depends on particular memory resource) and returned pointer is not obtained through dynamic memory allocation. Thus, deleting it results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

So, to properly handle deallocation for all memory resources, just use their `deallocate` method:

```
mr->deallocate(i1, sizeof(int));
```

Note that for `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` this operation is [no-op](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource/do_deallocate), while for `std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource` it is [not required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unsynchronized_pool_resource) (since it will deallocate obtained from upstream resource memory managed by it anyway during destruction), but may be beneficial if implementation uses it wisely to, e.g., deallocate some pool/chunk, all blocks from which were 'unregistered' by `deallocate`.

Also note that when objects are created in allocated memory by manually calling constructor through placement new, they should be manually destroyed by calling destructor, which can be done for all types (including built-in, for which you can't call directly using destructor syntax e.g. `~int()`) using [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at):

```
std::destroy_at(i1); // or c1; no-op for trivially destructible types
mr->deallocate(i1, sizeof(int)); // or c1
```

Comment: I used for simplicity pointer to ints. What if I allocate for a class instance, which I use a placement new (like in the example) to call the ctor. Can I then not call delete rather than the dtor and the deallocate function explicitly. This looks quite unsymmetrical to me:

Comment: @ThomasKrebs `deallocate` can't call dtor for deallocated objects since it doesn't know their types, so yes, explicit dtor call is necessary for non-trivially-destructible objects before deallocate. But the same call even for trivial types is also possible (resulting in no-op), albeit not directly, but through `p->~T()` where T is deduced to needed type within a template. Thus [std::destroy_at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at), which does exactly that, can be used to destroy object correctly irrespective of type.

Comment: @ThomasKrebs note that double delete can't happen for `destroy_at` followed by `deallocate` because, again, deallocate doesn't destroy object in any case. It calls just `::operator delete`, which, unlike *delete-expression*, doesn't call destructor.

Comment: @ThomasKrebs another option is to wrap your memory resource into `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138604/3162368).

Comment: A dtor/deallocate seems to work, but as the C++17 asks for the size of the object to delete I get another problem: In my container I use to hold the objects of concern I have pointers to possibly derived classes. To get the proper size for the deallocation I would need to get the size of the current object to delete. As sizeof is a compile time operator I would need to find out the class of the current instance likely via dynamic_cast, which is slow.

Comment: @ThomasKrebs If you don't want to manually destruct and deallocate each object, pointers to which you hold in container, you can wrap these pointers into smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) with custom deleters, where each deleter will remember size of dynamic type of held object. Or you can create your own specialized smart pointer like [here](https://buildingblock.ai/allocator-aware-smart-ptr).